# Is there a way to change the way items are displayed in my profile on SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, user-profiles

Is there a way to change the way items are displayed in my profile on SuperUser?

I would like to display my questions and answers in the order of newest to oldest, but I can find no way to set this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, then what you need is [Platypus](http://platypus.mozdev.org/).

> Platypus is a Firefox extension which
>   lets you modify a Web page from your
>   browser -- "What You See Is What You
>   Get" -- and then save those changes as
>   a Greasemonkey script so that they'll
>   be repeated the next time you visit
>   the page. Editing pages to suit your
>   needs is dandy -- but making those
>   changes "permanent" is the real
>   payoff.
>
> Some of the things you can do with
>   Platypus include:
>
> Remove parts of the page you don't wish to see.
>   Move a part of the page to a different location.
>   Change the style and format of page elements.
>   Modify all the links on the page using a regular expression.
>   Insert your own HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

on your profile page, there are 4 little boxes to the right and above your questions. Click on the one titled "Recent" (or maybe that should be "newest"? Experiment a little ;) )

Comment: recent is for activity, newest is when the question was originally asked.

Comment: I understand all that, but I want to change the default for how things are doisplayed always.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way currently to save the 'Recent' setting on the profile page.

Here's a [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/how-to-make-recent-activity-by-default) to question you can vote on to get it moved up the list.